# Verification of a list produces incorrect result

Tags: python

```
aArtsitNames = ["Artist Name: \"TwnetyOnePiloits\" "],["Artist Name: \"Bastile\" "]

aSongNamesBlanks = ["R___" ],["B__ N____"]

aSongNames = ["Ride"],["Bad News"]


print( aArtsitNames [0] )
print( aSongNamesBlanks [0] )

nUserAnswer = input("Enter the song name: ")

if nUserAnswer == aSongNames[0]:
    print ("correct")
```

This has more components to it but I stripped it down to try and get it working.
Can anyone help me with why this isn't working?

Comment: what is your expected output? what is your actual output? we're really going to need some more context...

Comment: what are you expecting exactly?

Comment: So if the input its the same as what is at position 0 in aSongNames it prints "correct"

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating the lists correctly. You are actually creating lists of lists. To create lists of strings, the correct syntax would be:

```
aArtsitNames = ["Artist Name: \"TwnetyOnePiloits\" ", "Artist Name: \"Bastile\" "]

aSongNamesBlanks = ["R___" , "B__ N____"]

aSongNames = ["Ride", "Bad News"]


print( aArtsitNames [0] )
print( aSongNamesBlanks [0] )

nUserAnswer = input("Enter the song name: ")

if nUserAnswer == aSongNames[0]:
    print ("correct")
```

Comment: Rather than "not creating lists", he was creating tuples of lists of one string each.

Answer (score 0):

you are not creating a list .
Try

```
aArtsitNames =[ "Artist Name: \"TwnetyOnePiloits\" ","Artist Name: \"Bastile\" " ]
```

Comment: huh its was still printing when i put  print( aArtsitNames [0] )

Comment: Trying accessing element using subscript but it's not subscripted properly.